# Documentdb in sitecore future release as xdb and analytics database

Tags: xdb

Is there any direction sitecore going to support documentdb as analytics database platform and go away from mongodb?

Comment: I am closing this as opinion-based. There is no way of knowing which direction Sitecore will go. There can be no definitive answers to this question, only speculation. As such, the question is not a good fit for the format of the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the relationship between Microsoft and Sitecore gets closer and closer, I think its definitely in the road map. The first person I heard about doing it was Sitecore George. https://twitter.com/sitecoregeorge/status/784151818385457152

https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/10/using-azure-documentdb-with-sitecore-xdb/

I think its definitely in the future.

Some bits for you to try
https://github.com/mathieu-benoit/azure-documentdb-for-sitecore